# How to restore second OS option on dual boot PC

Tags: windows, windows-xp, multi-boot

WinXP installed after Win7. The option to load Windows 7 disappeared. I need to restore the boot menu to be able to choose Windows 7.

Comment: You are probably going to need to boot from a Windows 7 installation media to fix the problem. I say this because the XP installation media has no idea for to configure for Windows 7. (How could it? Windows 7 did not exist.)

Comment: See this article, scroll down to "Create Boot Loader">>>>>https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8790/dual-boot-your-pre-installed-windows-7-computer-with-xp/

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem many time in dual booting specially when one OS need to be formatted

The boot menu of windows xp and windows NT is different and for windows 7 8 10 are different

The best way is to install lower version first and then new version ie windows 98,XP,7,2008,2010

Now of you want to format or repair any old version the way I did was to backup copy booting boot menu files  of windows 7  and windows xp and then  format or repair old windows XP add  new win xp is and after formatting repairing replace all new  files with old.files

Windows 7 creates a folder and files in the system active boot primary partition which is always C drive in which system  files and folders are  hidden

**Files In c:/ Root**

BootMgr
Root of the system partition

BCD
\Boot ( in folder directory)

(Copy backup all files  in C:\ root and  BOOT  hidden folder and  all files in boot folder)

NTLDR

**Files in e:/windows ( windows 7 partition)**

WinLoad
%SystemRoot%\System32

Ntoskrnl.exe
%SystemRoot%\System32

Hal.dll
%SystemRoot%\System32

Smss.exe
%SystemRoot%\System32

And many others in windows system which should be intact in windows 7 system32 folder else you have to reinstall  or repair windows

But now **your problem is that your boot menu have been replaced** by windows xp boot menu files and you have not taken back of boot menu BCD files and you have to recreate BCD boot menu

**Now 4 options you have to try which one can work  if it works or not to he back boot menu**

**1. Difficult technical  to Install windows 7 in new partition or a virtual partition or drive**

if you have space in hard disk or free partition of  4-8gb

You can see details in video link how to

[Video to reinstall win 7 on  virtual drive](https://youtu.be/BI29gq4QYqM)

```
https://youtu.be/BI29gq4QYqM
```

(Beware make backup of your data be safe using disk part and virtual disk as it can damage your partition table if wrong command given and all HDD data will be lost will have to recover partitions)

**2.  Install overwrite new windows 7**

A. Insert the original installation DVD or USB Drive. ...

B. Restart your computer.

C. Boot from the disc/USB..

D. At the Install screen, click install  and select windows 7 partition
(Risk dome softwares may not work and settings may refresh)

E. You can install and repair windows7

( it will install refresh windows 7 files and will recreate your boot menu and add windows xp and files)

**3. Fix #4: Rebuild the BCD**

A. Insert the original installation DVD or USB Drive.

B. Restart your computer.

C. Boot from the disc/USB.

D. At the Install screen, click Repair your computer or press R.

E. Click Troubleshoot.

F. Click Command Prompt.

Type these commands:

```
bootrec /FixMbr 

bootrec /FixBoot 

bootrec /ScanOs 

bootrec /RebuildBcd
```

G. Press Enter after each command

H. When the bootrec /
RebuildBcd command finished the process, remove the installation DVD/USB

I. Type exit and press Enter

J. Restart your computer

( it may or may not work depends on BCD files there or not)

**4. EASY RECOVERY ESSENTIAL**

A. Download Easy Recovery Essentials. Make sure to note your Windows version (XP, Vista, 7 or 8) before you download EasyRE.

B. Burn a CD and boot from it

C. Choose “Automated Repair” in Easy Recovery Essentials

After EasyRE scans your computer’s drives, identify and select the drive letter for your Windows installation from the list, and then click on the Automated Repair button to begin.

D. Choose the drive associated with the Windows installation you’re trying to repair.

Easy Recovery Essentials will start analyzing the selected drive for problems. EasyRE will test for and attempt to automatically correct errors with the disk, partition, bootsector, filesystem, bootloader, and registry. No intervention is required, as EasyRE’s repair is fully automated:

E. Easy Recovery Essentials searches for errors and makes corrections to the selected Windows installation.

Once the process is complete, EasyRE will report its findings. Click on the Restart button to reboot your PC and test the changes.

**Now your second question to enable administrator rights in windows xp**

Administrator is not disabled in windows xp as in  windows 7,8,10. But some modified versions may have been scripted and deactivated it

To enable it, right-click the Command Prompt on the Start menu (it is likely listed under Accessories), choose Run as administrator,

type

```
net user administrator /active:yes,
```

and press Enter. You should see a message stating that the command completed successfully.

```
net user administrator
```

To check status

Other ways to enable windows xp administrator

[enabling administrator in windows xp](https://www.top-password.com/blog/4-ways-to-enable-built-in-administrator-account-on-windows/)

If you forgot password of administrator then try to reset it in safe mode or through windows xp boot CD you can ask me for details for resseting password for administrator

> if you it helped you then vote up or accept answer if it did not you can ask and clarify your doubts and queries

Comment: SWA see if u don't have installation media of windows 7 download trial version from Microsoft  or cracked version   from torrents and if you dont want to to erase data create a new partition or virtual  partition carefully (option 1 YouTube video link) and it will not effect your data and keep your  data original windows 7 data  intact and  still y

Comment: @SWA If you still don't want to download windows 7 then  try 3rd and 4th  option to rebuild BCD or recover boot menu  it will work if winxp installed have not overwritten or delete Bootmngr and ntldr and BCD files in boot folder if its modified then these option will not work... There is option of creating a 3rd parry GRUB boot DOS menu through programming or using different tools which a difficult for layman or normal users  as pee knowledge and experience  I told u some easy method  yah thee must be some new tools or may party BCD recovery or building tools CDs but all have to search . I m b

Answer (score 0):

If one of OS is working and u can boot into it then i Founded a 3rd party software which can do the job EasyBCD

After Installing XP

1. Boot up the computer with the Windows XP CD and install XP as normal in the unpartitioned space that you’ve created. Once XP is installed, you will now find the computer will boot straight to it as if Windows 7 doesn’t exist and there will be no boot menu. This is because the Master Boot Record of the boot drive has now been told to look for NTLDR which boots XP, and not BOOTMGR which is needed to boot 7 and its Boot Manager.
2. Download and install Neosmart EasyBCD . You WILL need Microsoft .NET Framework version 2 installed first for EasyBCD to work. If you haven’t yet updated your XP install, you can download Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2  as a standalone package.
3. Run EasyBCD and click on the BCD Deployment button down the left. Under MBR Configuration Options, make sure “Install the Vista/7 bootloader to the MBR” is selected and press Write MBR.

[image: Neosmart BCD picturee]

4. Click the Add New Entry button and set the Type to Windows NT/2k/XP/2k3 in the Windows tab drop down. Then press Add Entry, you can change the name before clicking to add but leave all other settings alone.

[image: Neosnart BCD picture working]

An optional measure is to change the boot order and timeout which can be done by using the Edit Boot Menu button. Simply tick the box for the default boot o/s and change the number of seconds from 30 if you want, then press Save Settings.

Note: If you receive any errors in EasyBCD about failing to add an entry to the boot menu, there is a way to get around this. Simply reboot the computer and it will now boot into Windows 7 automatically. Find and run the EasyBCD program in the XP partition\Program Files\Neosmart Technologies\EasyBCD folder, and repeat this step again.

5. Reboot your computer and you should have two entries in the Windows Boot Manager with the default already highlighted. You can now boot into either operating system.

See following links for video and detailed steps to use software

Click on the EasyBCD image to see some screenshots and use them as a guide.

https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

User Guide

https://neosmart.net/wiki/

How to: Dual-Boot Windows XP and Windows 7 (7 installed first)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmCZvrctECE

Install Windows XP in Dual Boot with Pre-Installed Windows 7 by Britec

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWRewE5GIcE

[EasyBCD Dual Boot Menu Set UP - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfuIKIDZ6A8)

[How to Dual Boot Windows 7 and XP](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/dual-boot/windows-xp/installing-second/&ved=2ahUKEwi7pozG6-TnAhWQbysKHZlWBQsQFjAHegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3MyupHv5RYD4wSVuELjp0k&cshid=1582368573119)

> if it worked and helped you vote my answer or accept and for any further help questions feel free to ask doubts and queries

Answer (score -1):

Try booting into safe mode. Type msconfig in the windows search bar. Click on msconfig, if it shows up. From there you should be able to edit boot options for operating systems . If this doesn't work you could try to edit boot options in your system Bios.